# In Inter thread processes why main thread behave badly, when child executed first?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning threading in java and wrote following code.
Here:
I am creating two threads (main and t) and i want to implements inter-thread communication. Here is two scenarios :

1) If Main thread executed first/continue then Main thread acquire lock on object "t", release lock and go for waiting state (

```
synchronized (t) {
    System.out.println("waiting " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    t.wait();
}
```

). Child thread take place and complete its work and notify Main thread. Main thread get started and print final output `System.out.println(t.total)`. Its OK, for me.

2) If child thread executed first then child thread complete its working (

```
synchronized (this) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
        total = total + i;
    }
    System.out.println("------------" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "calling notify" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    this.notify();
   }
```

) and call notify at last. What happen when its call notify, because no one is waiting?? next question is Main thread is waiting life time or not?? If not then why not waiting.

Below is the code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        T t = new T();
        t.setPriority(10);
        t.start();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        synchronized (t) {
            System.out.println("waiting " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            t.wait();
        }
        System.out.println(t.total);
    }
}

class T extends Thread {
    public int total = 0;
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
                total = total + i;
            }
            System.out.println("------------" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "calling notify" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            this.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Questions: When child thread run first some times program(Main thread) ended/complete successfully or some time Main thread goes for waiting, Why???

Following is the output:

```
------------Thread-0calling notify1490271423920

waiting main 1490271423921
```

In this case Main thread is alive.

```
------------Thread-0calling notify1490272176789
waiting main 1490272176789
4950
```

In this case Main thread ended successfully.
Why its happening??

Thanks.

Comment: You probably should avoid synchronizing on any thread object, and you definitely should avoid using wait()/notify() on a thread object.  The Thread class does all of the above on thread objects for its own purposes, and if you do it too, your synchronization may interact with the thread object's own synchronization in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happen when its call notify, because no one is waiting??

Nothing happens.

> next question is Main thread is waiting life time or not?? If not then why not waiting.

Sorry, I didn't understand your question.

> Questions: When child thread run first some times program(Main thread) ended/complete successfully or some time Main thread goes for waiting, Why???

If `this.notify()` is executed before `t.wait()`, then the main thread will wait forever, hanging the program execution.

By your code design I guess you want, at this speficic order:

- the main thread to start T thread and `wait()`
- then the T thread to run its code and call `notify()`
- then main thread to print result and finish

But your code allows a **race condition** in that the second bullet may start and finish before the first bullet finishes, causing the undesired behavior.

Comment: and why this happening ? why same code, same situation (when child called first)  gives different output @nandsito

Comment: @sawaisingh this is what the race condition is about: there is no guarantee of which thread will run first. Race conditions are almost always undesirable, so you have to design your code in a way that they won't happen

Comment: @sawaisingh look for `java prevent race condition` in your favorite search engine, there'll be plenty of results

Comment: Thanks, I am not asking, how can i resolve this thing, I am asking why its happening?. Now, suppose I put `Thread.sleep(1000);` before  `synchronized (t)`. Now we can say child thread first executed now. Then???

Comment: child executed first (just suppose) and complete its work. Then why not Main thread go for infinite waiting all times (Why only some time)??.

Comment: @sawaisingh race conditions happen *because* programmers don't have control over the operating system thread scheduler, and race conditions happen *when* programmers aren't careful enough

Comment: @sawaisingh if you put that `Thread.sleep(1000)` you *almost always* guarantee that the child will run before the main thread, that is, the bullets in my answer will happen in that order, and the main thread won't hang. I say "almost always" because `sleep` is a poor design for preventing race conditions

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of best practices related to using wait/notify.  All of this information is available online.  Some key points:

- use `notifyAll` unless you *really* know what you are doing
- always `wait` in a loop (spurious wakeups)
- use an additional "status" variable which reflects the current shared state.  notification doesn't reflect *any* status, it just wakes up others that are waiting.

the last point is most relevant to your current issue.  when you `notifyAll`, you should also set some sort of status which reflects the intent of the notification.

e.g.

```
 // thread
 sync() {
   done = true;
   notifyAll()
 }

 // main
 sync() {
   while(!done) {
     wait();
   }
 }
```

Comment: and why this happening ? why same code, same situation (when child called first)  gives different output